# python:use a function to remove a list element,I get confused with the result

Tags: python, list

```
def testf(st):
    st=st[1:]
    print st
def popf(st):
    st.pop(0)
    print st
a = ["response", ["wis", "hello"], ["deng", "shen"]]
testf(a)
print a
a = ["response", ["wis", "hello"], ["deng", "shen"]]
popf(a)
print a
```

Below is the output:

```
[['wis', 'hello'], ['deng', 'shen']]
['response', ['wis', 'hello'], ['deng', 'shen']]
[['wis', 'hello'], ['deng', 'shen']]
[['wis', 'hello'], ['deng', 'shen']]
```

I want to use a function to delete a list element, but I'm confused why the function `testf()` can't delete the element after the function but the `popf()` function can do. what's the difference? if not in the function, `st=st[1:] = st.pop(0)` (`del st[0]` also works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first function you are assigning a new value to `st` in this statement so it is a completely new variable and not the one passed as the argument:

```
st = st[1:]
```

You can check it using `id` before and after assignment:

```
In [13]: def testf(st):
   ....:     print('before: ', id(st))
   ....:     st = st[1:]
   ....:     print('after: ', id(st))
   ....:

In [14]: a = ["response", ["wis", "hello"], ["deng", "shen"]]

In [15]: id(a)
Out[15]: 85287112L

In [16]: testf(a)
('before: ', 85287112L)
('after: ', 85289480L)
```

But in the second function there is no assignment hence the id remains same. It means you modified the list passed in the arguments:

```
In [17]: def popf(st):
   ....:     print('before: ', id(st))
   ....:     st.pop(0)
   ....:     print('after: ', id(st))
   ....:

In [18]: popf(a)
('before: ', 85287112L)
('after: ', 85287112L)
```

Answer (score 0):

`popf` mutates the `st` list that it is passed. `testf` does not: it simply overwrites the name with another list that is a copy without the first element.